# convert kendo chart type

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, scatter

I have a kendo's scatterline chart on my HTML page.
I have generated it as following.

```
objchart = $("#chart").kendoChart({
dataSource: {
    data: Chartdata                                
},
background: mainbackground,                        
series: [{
    type: "scatterLine",                           
    xField: "date"                                 
}],
xAxis: {
    title: {
        text: "Date"                               
    },
    min: min_date,                                 
    max: max_date,                                 
    name: "Date",                                  
    template: "#= kendo.toString(value,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')#",
    type: "date",                                  
    baseUnit: "seconds",                           
    background: xaxisbackcolor,                    
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: "Closing stock prices"               
    },
    min: min_close,                                
    max: max_symbol,                               
    background: yaxisbackcolor,                    
},
title: {
    text: "Close and Volume Date-wise"             
},
transitions: false,
zoom: setRange,                                    
dragStart: onDragStart,                            
drag: onDrag,                                      
dragEnd: onDragEnd                                 
}).data("kendoChart");
```

Following is my datasource (calling from web api)

```
[{"date":"9/14/2015 1:20:00 AM","close":6.0,"volume":18.0,"open":58.0,"high":42.0,"low":60.0,"symbol":79.0}]
```

Now, I need to change the type of the chart from scatter line chart into others like series and bar chart.
when I change it as objchart.options.series[0].type = "column", it does not give any output.
It only leaves the blank chart behind.

What is the correct method to change or cast the chart from any type to any other type?

Thank you

Comment: it would be nice if you can provide jsfiddle demo or kendo dojo demo.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Maharshi/wragrx6h/

Comment: As per my knowledge bar chart and scatter chart have different properties so we can not easily change it by using its type at run time. You have to recreate it manually.